# How to get the portal object after user login using IUserLoggedInEvent

Tags: plone

I'm trying to get  the portal object after user login to create a folder. Right now, I'm using the below event subscribers. Is there a better way to do this?

```
<subscriber
    for="*
         Products.PluggableAuthService.interfaces.events.IUserLoggedInEvent"
    handler=".subscribers.createProfile"
/>

def createProfile(obj, event):
    portal = getToolByName(obj.REQUEST.PUBLISHED, 'portal_url').getPortalObject()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `getSite()` function:

```
from zope.component.hooks import getSite

site = getSite() # returns portal root from thread local storage
```

Answer (score 1):

Martijn is right on spot (as always), but you could also give [plone.api](http://ploneapi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) a spin - it is even easier:

```
from plone import api

portal = api.portal.get()
```